# Where can I find statistics on OS usage?

Tags: language-agnostic, operating-system

I am trying to decide whether it is worth it or not to put in the time to make an app work on Windows 2000 and/or Windows 98, so I'm curious to find out how many people are still using these operating systems.

Thanks, as always.

Comment: Why does someone think this belongs on Super User? It's a programming question (though it's not a *coding* question)

Comment: I agree that this should stay on stackoverflow, as programmers care most about this sort of thing, its not really a general computer/software question.

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question - what you want to know is what OS's are your potential customers using.  If your customers are primarily people who have bought a new PC in the last 8 years you shouldn't care about either 98 or 2000.

Answer (score 1):

[w3 operating system statistics](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_os.asp) (win 2000: 0.7%)

[w3 counter operating system statistics](http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php) (win 2000: 0.54%)

Frankly, its going to be a lot of work to support those operating systems, and unless you have specific reason to, you probably shouldn't. You should probably just support XP and up for an "average" windows application, as that won't be difficult to code, and because the next earliest version, win 2003, is below 2% in both of those charts. :D

Also possibly of interest: [.net framework installation statistics](http://www.nbdtech.com/blog/archive/2009/05/25/what-percentage-of-users-have-the-.net-framework-installed-and.aspx)

[deployment rate of the .net framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65749/what-is-the-deployment-rate-of-the-net-framework)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you should NOT add support for ancient versions of operating systems unless there are customers who are really desperate for it.

People who are still using 9X and 2000 need to be given every encouragement to move to a newer OS platform.  It is really for their own good.

Comment: You're right. I'm writing for a school market and, not uncommonly, when people make the decision to upgrade they want to donate their old machine to a school. ... Still, I don't think I'm going to support Win98 or Win2000 thanks to the responses here.

Comment: There are always customers who are desparate for it. I had to write a program just recently for an old Commodore! Now THAT'S ancient

Comment: @baeltazor - desperate enough to pay you 10+ times the going rate?  Otherwise, that's not desperate enough IMO.